# Android Cursor on Contacts shows more contacts than the People app

Tags: android, duplicates, contacts, hidden

I am getting the contacts on an android via the new API.

The problem is that I get more contacts than I can see on the People app on the device. 
In the app I see, among other contacts created by the sync adapter sample app, 2 contacts associated with the google account on the device.
When I look in the DB file extracted from the device I can see these contacts as duplicates. That is they have different contact_ids, but the same info (just an e-mail address.). 
I then changed on of them in the People app by adding more information (given name, suffix, etc). This contacts gets changed ion the DB file as well, but the other, the "duplicate" remains the same.

Can anyone give me a hint of what is going on there?

Cheers, 
Alex

Answer (score 0):

This is because the contacts comes from different accounts. For example when contacts are sync from two different email accounts, some contact may have exactly the same info. The contacts table store them as different items.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. I have doubts that the contacts come from different accounts. In the DB file they appear as having the same account_id. Moreover, I have uninstalled the Sample app and it got rid of all the specific contacts associated with that particular account. Still my duplicates remain...

Comment: Just noted that the visible_contacts table only contains the IDs of the contacts I am seeing on the People app....

Comment: how can i query this visible_contacts table?